# matplotlib does not import PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, canopy

I'm using Canopy 2.1.3 distribution (on Ubuntu 16.04) which as you may know contains the matplotlib package. Simply running in the Canopy's shell `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` gives me

> ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,
>   or PySide package to be installed, but it was not found.

I have installed all of the three packages with Synaptic but the problem persists. 
Could this be related to environment variables? Or, could it be because Canopy's Python 3.5 and Ubuntu's Python 2.7 are conflicting?

EDIT:
I have finally used the PyQt by installing it from the Canopy's package manager.

Comment: Questions and answers should be useful for future readers. So I would invite you to instead of giving a one-sentence answer within the question, provide a full answer with more details such that other people having the same problem in the future can benefit from it.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely that the default backend for `matplotlib.pyplot` is set to `qt`.
I have very little experience with canopy, but it should be possible to change the default to another back end; maybe someone else will be able to tell you how, or you can find it by yourself.

In the meantime, you can try to add this above all other matplotlib imports:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Answer (score 2):

From the user guide:

> [Known Issue: In Canopy running Python 3, GUI backend must be explicitly set](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/2.1/configure/release-notes.html#known-issue-python-version-specified-in-code-editor-s-status-bar-is-ignored-3366-3740)
>
> If you ask matplotlib to display a plot, or otherwise run Python code that creates a GUI window, by default you will get an error traceback ending with: ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
>
> The solutions are to install PyQt (which is GPL-licensed) in the Canopy Package Manager, or to use the Canopy Preference menu’s Python tab to specify the TK PyLab backend for creating GUIs. For details, see [“Python 3 in Canopy 2 - ‘No module named PyQt4’ error”](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001655566-Python-3-in-Canopy-2-No-module-named-PyQt4-error)